# Page not found with new content

Tags: users

I just create a new content type and add a couple of nodes but I get 'The requested page could not be found.' message with anonymous users, apparently the nodes of this new content type require admin permissions, I've been searching on user management and enable access content but for this particular content type still need admin permission, any idea?

Comment: Are you using any custom theme or default drupal themes ?
Also check permissions if you are using "Node access module"

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a caching issue.

'The requested page could not be found.' is not the same as 'You are not authorized to access this page.'

Because you can see the page as the admin account but not as an anonymous user, I believe you can fix this issue by flushing your Drupal caches.

The admin account doesn't show cached content by default but the anonymous users do.

There are several ways to [Clear Drupal's Cache](https://www.drupal.org/node/42055) but the simplest is likely to go to admin/config/development/performance.

If you use drush, simply run 'drush cc all'

Comment: yeah, drupal cache was my first approach but even cleaning the cache I get the same result, that's weird

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following things:-

Firslty when we creating a node of particular content type:-

[image]

Check that node is published or not.

and then

[image]

Checkout the permissions and give permissions to those roles that can view the node.

If you have given permission to anonymous user then any one can view the node.

Node can now be shown to anonymous users if it is not viewing then one time clear the cahe and then check.

Comment: I forgot to mention that is a drupal 6 installation, the node is marked as published and access content permission it's enabled to anonymous users, no changes.